# Create Unique ID based on a column and calculate the mean based on the generated ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to generate unique ID for each event/episode and then wanted to calculate the mean of a column based on the generated ID.

Here is an example:

| Event | Val |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 5 |

First,
I would like to create an ID column as below,

| Event | Val | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | A1 |
| A | 5 | A1 |
| A | 1 | A1 |
| B | 8 | B1 |
| B | 2 | B1 |
| C | 1 | C1 |
| C | 3 | C1 |
| A | 2 | A2 |
| A | 5 | A2 |

Second,
I would like to calculate the mean of 'Val' based on the generated ID column.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

I tried 'cumsum' and 'duplicated' function, but that tend to generate continous ID numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution, use `mutate` if you want to add the mean as a new column instead of reduce the number of rows to one-per-group.

```
library(dplyr)
  
df %>% 
  group_by(ID = paste0(Event, cumsum(lag(Event, default = first(Event)) != Event) + 1)) %>% 
  summarize(Val = mean(Val), .groups = "drop")
```

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
    Event = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A"),
    Val = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L)
  )

DT[, ID := rleid(Event)][, ID := rleid(ID), by = Event][, ID := paste0(Event, ID)][, mean := mean(Val), by = ID]
```

---

```
> DT
   Event Val ID mean
1:     A   3 A1  3.0
2:     A   5 A1  3.0
3:     A   1 A1  3.0
4:     B   8 B1  5.0
5:     B   2 B1  5.0
6:     C   1 C1  2.0
7:     C   3 C1  2.0
8:     A   2 A2  3.5
9:     A   5 A2  3.5
```

Comment: Very clever use of `rleid` +1

Comment: I think the clever part is using it twice?

Comment: Yep, exactly, and by group too

Answer (score 4):

A similar approach than @ismirsehregal but with `dplyr`. Note that `consecutive_id` was introduced with `dplyr 1.1.0`, the latest dplyr update.

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0+ 
df %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(Event)) %>% 
  mutate(id = paste0(Event, consecutive_id(id)), .by = Event) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(Val), .by = id)

  Event Val id mean
1     A   3 A1  3.0
2     A   5 A1  3.0
3     A   1 A1  3.0
4     B   8 B1  5.0
5     B   2 B1  5.0
6     C   1 C1  2.0
7     C   3 C1  2.0
8     A   2 A2  3.5
9     A   5 A2  3.5
```

---

And another approach based on `cumsum` and non-consecutive `row_number`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(id = paste0(Event, cumsum(c(0, diff(id)) != 1)), .by = Event) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(Val), .by = id)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update the first answer is not correct!**

Here the correct version (thanks to @Maël) I used his `consecutive_id` approach with `rleid`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = rleid(Event)) %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste0(Event, rleid(ID)), .by = Event) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(Val), .by = ID)

  Event Val ID mean
1     A   3 A1  3.0
2     A   5 A1  3.0
3     A   1 A1  3.0
4     B   8 B1  5.0
5     B   2 B1  5.0
6     C   1 C1  2.0
7     C   3 C1  2.0
8     A   2 A2  3.5
9     A   5 A2  3.5
```

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID = rleid(Event)) %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste0(Event, rleid(ID)), .by = Event) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(Val), .by = ID)
```

**First answer: NOT correct!**
Inspired by the solution of @ismirsehregal here a dplyr version:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(Event) %>%
    mutate(ID = paste0(Event, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Val != lag(Val, default = first(Val))) != 0)))) %>%
    group_by(Event, ID) %>%
    mutate(mean = mean(Val)) %>%
    ungroup()

 Event   Val ID     mean
  <chr> <int> <chr> <dbl>
1 A         3 A1     3   
2 A         5 A2     3.25
3 A         1 A2     3.25
4 B         8 B1     8   
5 B         2 B2     2   
6 C         1 C1     1   
7 C         3 C2     3   
8 A         2 A2     3.25
9 A         5 A2     3.25
```

Comment: But ID is not correct, right? It should be C1 C1 for instance

Comment: Thats true. Will fix it. Thanks for reminding.